# Cannot print the list return value from axios get using v-for

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, axios

I am new to Vue.js, so I am building a simple html with vue.js website and show the axios get result from myphpadmin data. Everything works fine until the end I cannot show the json message on my screen.

```
new Vue({

el: "#app",

data() {
  return {      
    databaseList: [] , // the list result is store into response.data.show_all_mfug?
    inputt: {mfug: ""},
  };
},

mounted(){
  this.readMfug();
},

methods:{
  readMfug(){
    axios.get("http://localhost/products_db/read_php/read_mfug.php?action=read").then(function(response) {
      let json = response.data;
      app.databaseList = response.data.show_all_mfug;
      console.log("AA. ", app.databaseList ); //DEBUG PRINT
    }

  },
```

In the line AA., it can show this json successfully
[image]

After I can reflect from axios get, I want to transfer my json stuff `0 :  {mfugkey: '1', mfugname: 'AAAAAAAAA'}` to my html page.

The html page is like this below:

```
<div v-for="show_all_mfug in databaseList" >
        {{show_all_mfug}}
        {{show_all_mfug.mfugkey}}
</div>
```

Both of the {{ }} does show nothing. the mfugkey which is 1 from {{show_all_mfug.mfugkey}}?

If you need php this is the one below:

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "zion_test_db");
if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection Failed!">$conn->connect_error); //no connection error
}

ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$result = array('error'=>false);
$action = "";

if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    $action = $_GET['action'];

}
if($action == "read"){
    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM ALL_MFUG");
    $show_all_mfug = array();
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        array_push($show_all_mfug, $row);
    }

    $result['show_all_mfug'] = $show_all_mfug;
    echo json_encode($result);
}
?>
```

It show the json successfully in axios.get, every backend works fine, reflect the mfugname and key , but while I use **v-for** it has nothing? Thank you to have a look in advanced and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `app.` portion. `databaseList = response.data.show_all_mfug;` should be the correct way to access the data property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like vue2, so you'll likely need to access your data properties through the `this` keyword as opposed to `app`, so for example:

```
this.databaseList = response.data.show_all_mfug
```

You could also skip the line where you set json = response.data since you never use that variable.

Comment: thanks, now I know in order to refer the list I have to type 'this' instead of 'app'. I will remember that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **this** keyword  since you are using vue2 `this.databaseList=response.data.show_all_mfug`

Comment: This is identical to the answer already posted, except it doesn't have any explanation. Take a look again at [ask]